# fetch values from firebase Realtime database and compare them to form input using flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm working on flutter form validation, and I want to check if the input values match values that already exist in the database.

here's some of my code:

```
late DatabaseReference dbRef;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    dbRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref().child('/Suppliers/');
  }
```

```
Directionality(
textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
child: TextFormField(
  validator: (value) {
    if (value == "") {
      return "you must provide a username";
    } else if (value != null && value.length < 6) {
      return "username can't be shorter than 6";
    } else if (dbRef
            .orderByChild("username")
            .equalTo(
                _accountUserNameController.value) ==
        _accountUserNameController.value) {
      return "username already exists";
    }
    return null;
  },
  controller: _accountUserNameController,
  style: TextStyle(
    fontSize: 16.0,
  ),
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    labelText: "إسم المستخدم",
    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
    prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.account_circle_rounded),
  ),
),
```

all of the validation I added works just fine except when I add this part

```
else if (dbRef
        .orderByChild("username")
        .equalTo(
            _accountUserNameController.value) ==
    _accountUserNameController.value) {
  return "username already exists";
}
```

in attempt to check if the input value matches any value already stored in the database.

Answer (score 0):

This code defines a query, but it doesn't load any data from the database yet:

```
dbRef
  .orderByChild("username")
  .equalTo(
    _accountUserNameController.value)
```

To actually [load the data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/flutter/read-and-write#read_once_using_get) you'll need to call `get()` on the query, and then check if the snapshot you get back exists.